# Wordpress checked="checked" syntax

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, checked

Only a few week age, I established a simple plugin for myself to showing the social share button in menu. Referred to [Building Your Own Social Sharing Plugin for WordPress](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-your-own-social-sharing-plugin-for-wordpress/).

Then, the plugin was successful created. But I have a question of the syntax why If I added the below syntax in the program the checked="checked" will showing twice.

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='social-share' value='1' " . checked(1, get_option('social-share'), true) ." /> ";
```

After that, I found another code to prevent this happen.

```
?>
  <input type="checkbox" name="social-share" value="1" <?php checked(1, get_option('social-share'), true); ?> /> Check for Yes
<?php
```

and [Function Reference/checked displaying checked='checked'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843872/function-reference-checked-displaying-checked-checked/43932268#43932268)

```
checked( '1', get_option( 'wwo_enable_'.$lrole ), false )
```

I wondered if anyone can tell me why using HTML format to show the `<?php checked(1, get_option('social-share-wechat'), true); ?>` syntax will not show twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were seeing unexpected results because you were echoing a function that was already generating output.

The third argument for `checked()` is 'echo' which determines whether the function should output a value or return it instead. You needed the function to return a value in the context you were using it in.

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="social-share" value="1" ' . checked( 1, get_option( 'social-share' ), false ) . '/>';
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked

The code you replaced it with handles things differently:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="social-share" value="1" <?php checked(1, get_option('social-share'), true); ?> />
```

Here you're no longer echoing the result of `checked()` therefore you do want it to generate output so it's correct to set the third argument to true.

Comment: Hi @Nathan Dawson, thank you for your response. Do you mean echo the `checked( 1, get_option( 'social-share' ), true )` will return another echo result so that it will display **checked="checked"** twice?

Comment: When you set the third argument, `echo`, to true in `checked()` it's going to output the checked string. You were using it in an echo statement so you needed the value to be returned, not output.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Will you please try below thing:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="social-share" value="1" <?php if ( 1 == get_option('social-share') ) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> >
```

Comment: The code you've posted is the whole reason the `checked()` function exists.